# Adding a Header View for PullToRefreshListView

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I want to add a custom view as header for the `PullToRefreshListView`. As, we have `public void addHeaderView (View v)` to set header for the `ListView`, I couldn't find one for `PullToRefreshListView`. If anybody has done anything similar to this please suggest me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution myself. It's very simple. Following code snippet will help us to add header view to the `PullToRefreshListView` :

```
final PullToRefreshListView v = (PullToRefreshListView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.list);
v.setOnRefreshListener(this);
final ListView lv = v.getRefreshableView();
TextView view = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.text);
lv.addHeaderView(view);
```

Comment: How I corelate after the list view lv to pulltorefresh v?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
listView.getRefreshableView().addHeaderView(header);
```

it should work too.